# Inner join 2 tables by 2 categories and multiple columns

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have 2 tables: `Candidates` and `Jobs`.

In `Jobs` there are columns `Profession` and `Subprofession`.

For each row in `Candidates` there are 8 columns:

```
Selected_Profession1, Selected_Subprofession1, 
Selected_Profession2, Selected_Subprofession2, 
Selected_Profession3, Selected_Subprofession3, 
Selected_Profession4, Selected_Subprofession4
```

I would like to make a query that would select all the jobs whose profession and subprofession are in one of the respective fields in the `Candidates` table.

So let's say we have the following Jobs table:

```
(profession subprofession) ----->   (100, 200)
                                    (100, 201)
                                    (101, 200)
                                    (101, 201)
```

and the following Candidates table:

```
(prof1 subprof1 prof2 subprof2 prof3 subprof3 prof4 subprof4) ---->  
(100,  200,     300,  400,     100,  200,     100,  300)
(101,  200,     102,  200,     300,  200,     200,  300)
(100,  200,     300,  400,     101,  201,     100,  300)
(101,  101,     200,  200,     300,  300,     400,  400)
```

The query will return rows 1, 3 and 4 from the Jobs table (because Candidate 1 has the pair 100, 200 and candidate 2 has the pair 101, 200 and candidate 3 has the pair 101, 201).

Hope this is clear enough...

Comment: If I were you, I'd normalise your data structures before you go any further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the join on multiple fields with an `or` condition:

```
select j.*
from jobs j join
     candidates c
     on (j.prof = c.prof1 and j.subprof = c.subprof1) or
        (j.prof = c.prof2 and j.subprof = c.subprof2) or
        (j.prof = c.prof3 and j.subprof = c.subprof3) or
        (j.prof = c.prof4 and j.subprof = c.subprof4);
```

If you have large tables, the performance on this will not be very good.  You can fix the data structure to get better performance, by having a `CandidateProf` table, where each prof/subprof pair is on a different row.

With the data structure you have, you would get better performance with separate joins for each prof/subprof grouping, particularly by having an index on the pair.  The problem is the `select` clause.  So:

```
select distinct j.*
from jobs j lef outer join
     candidates c1
     on (j.prof = c1.prof1 and j.subprof = c1.subprof1) left outer join
     candidates c2
     on (j.prof = c2.prof2 and j.subprof = c2.subprof2) left outer join
     . . .
where c1.prof1 is not null or c2.prof1 is not null or
      c3.prof1 is not null or c4.prof1 is not null
```

And you need to remove duplicates because one candidate might have multiple qualifications.

Comment: Second query looks good, just would select j.* since OP wants distinct rows from jobs table making the query a little easier (the query will return rows 1, 3 and 4 from the Jobs table...).

Comment: @sgeddes . . . Thank you for pointing that out.  I changed the solution to pull jobs rather than candidates (you still need the distinct in the second case, though because multiple candidates might qualify producing multiple rows).

Comment: +1 Looks good -- was thinking distinct as I wrote it in my comment.

Comment: The second query doesn't seem like a good suggestion to me. For the OP's example, in particular, it would return no rows. In general, it would return rows only if there were candidates with all the four pairs matching some of those in the `jobs` table. Perhaps you meant using left joins and subsequently `WHERE c1.prof IS NOT NULL OR c2.prof IS NOT NULL ...`.

Comment: @AndriyM . . . I see exactly what you are saying.  Getting that second version (which would definitely use indexes) is a bit harder than I first thought.  Need to change to `left outer join`s and check for a match in the `where` clause.

Comment: You seem to have reacted really fast! Did my comment catch you in the middle of the editing process? I'm sorry if it did, it appears I lacked just a tiny bit of patience to wait before laying out my thoughts! And I agree with you entirely, the second version does indeed turn out more complicated than it may have seemed initially.

Comment: @AndriyM . . . The most valuable course I took in high school was touch typing ;)

Comment: Oh yes, that skill can take one a long way, especially when assisted with a good keyboard. (I mean I don't know if bad keyboards can be found in circulation in your country but yours most probably isn't one of them.)

Answer (score 0):

If your data structures were normalised, this kind of query becomes easier, and your database becomes more flexible.

IE : Your table should look more like

```
 CandidateID ProfessionOrder Profession SubProfession
 1           1               100        200
 1           2               300        400
 ...
 2           1               101        200
```

The following query based on your current data structures firstly normalises the candidate/professions table, and then joins in order to demonstrate the ease of finding the solution with normalised data structures.

```
select 
     candidateid
from
     jobs
inner join
(
    select 
        candidateid, prof1 as profession,  subprof1 as subprofession
    from candidates
    union
    select 
        candidateid, prof2 ,  subprof2
    from candidates
    union
    select 
        candidateid, prof3 ,  subprof3
    from candidates
    union
    select 
        candidateid, prof4 ,  subprof4
    from candidates
) candidates
    on jobs.profession = candidates.profession
    and jobs.subprofession = candidates.subprofession
```

Comment: This needs help to be accurate -- where are all your FROM clauses?

Comment: No worries -- 4 more to go and then this will look good as well.

Comment: @sgeddes I think I shall go back to bed now.